# Desktop notifications for another user

Tags: php, notifications

I'm editing an online service where customers can make purchases, which are then computed by a team of "admins".

I'd like to setup desktop notifications whenever a customer buys something, but I'd like the admins to get it (instead of the "current browser", which is the customer's).

Is there a simple way to achieve this, or should I consider using something like Pusher.js to send the "events" to the admin's browsers ?

(I understand that admins will have to let a browser tab open on the website, that's not an issue. FYI it's a Laravel 5.2 project)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not relevant now, but a few years back you could install Growl on the machines, and send notifications via Growl's GNTP protocol to send notifications to their machines.

Growl hasn't been support for some time I think...

However, you could look into [pushover](https://pushover.net/) which has an API so you just queue up some notifications and set up a PHP CRON to send notifications to the pushover API, which in turn will send the notifications to the machines with the software installed.